# Javascript setter returns value without validation

Tags: javascript, getter-setter, javascript-objects, ecmascript-5, javascript-engine

JavaScript setter updates the internal value at the reference but the return value is not correct.

```
var Game = 
{   
    get points() {
        return this._points;
},

    set points(x){        
       x = Math.min(x,25);

       this._points = x;   
       return this._points;
    }
};

Game.points = 10 ;

console.log(Game.points); // outputs 10

var updatedPoints = (Game.points = 60);

console.log(updatedPoints); // outputs 60
console.log(Game.points); // outputs 25
```

Expected value for 'updatedPoints' was 25 !

Any idea why this could be happening ? Can you suggest if there is a way to fix this ?

Reason to fix this: To make sure the JS code performs as expected , maintainibility !

Comment: @FelixKling one would expect the value for updatedPoints to be 25 ?

Comment: Yeah I understood your question now. But no, the result of an assignment expression is that value that was assigned (which is 60).

Comment: I'd use a comma operator - it's shorter :P
var updatedPoints = ( (Game.points = 60), Game.points );

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JavaScript simple assignement (`=`) returns the right value as per the specification ([11.13.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1)). This behavior ignores whatever validation happens in your setter.

From the spec:

> The production *AssignmentExpression* : *LeftHandSideExpression* =
>   *AssignmentExpression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *lref* be the result of evaluating *LeftHandSideExpression*.
> 2. Let *rref* be the result of evaluating *AssignmentExpression*.
> 3. Let *rval* be GetValue(*rref*).
> 4. Throw a **SyntaxError** exception if the following conditions are all true:
>
>    - Type(*lref*) is Reference is **true**
>    - IsStrictReference(*lref*) is **true**
>    - Type(GetBase(*lref*)) is Environment Record
>    - GetReferencedName(*lref*) is either "**eval**" or "**arguments**"
> 5. Call PutValue(*lref*, *rval*).
> 6. Return *rval*.

So there is no way to "fix" your issue as it is by design. Checking `Game.points` should be enough.

Comment: I am changing an object to getter-setter format, but this can have side effects at the existing references in the legacy code if a reference is made like the way i showed above.

Comment: @sbr Ah I see. Then yeah, you might have an issue but I'm afraid there is no way around it. Though one might argue that modifying the value in the setter is bad practice since the caller does not expect that to happen. Throwing an error if `x > 25` would avoid the issue at hand, if you can live with that kind of behavior. Good luck!

Comment: The main reason of implementing it through a setter is validation and coercion. Can you think of a better way to attach a validator method to every assignment ? something concise like this one. Thanks

Comment: Well usually a validation does not modify input, it checks if it is valid and blocks the input in some way if it isn't. That's why I suggested throwing an exception instead of modifying the value. Other than that I don't know. Hard to tell what would make sense for you without really diving in your project...